# Storing an vector iterator inside another vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I can't figure out the signature required to store an iterator inside a vector. All my google foo just shows me how to use iterators on vectors.

Comment: There are no iterator type in isolations, they're always iterators associated to other container. If you just need to store iterators specific to a container, look at @juanchopanza solution.... If you need to store any iterator, that's probably not possible.

Comment: Beware that this may become dangerous if you store the iterators and later change or delete the original container.

Comment: @user2734679 Why would you need this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct Foo {};
std::vector<Foo> v; // vector of Foos
std::vector<std::vector<Foo>::iterator> vi; // vector of iterators of vector of Foos
```

Comment: Do not forget that type alias are your friends, `using Foos = std::vector<Foo>;` result to an easer readable `std::vector<Foos::iterator>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> v1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> v2;
v2.reserve( v1.size() );

for ( std::vector<int>::iterator it = v1.begin(); it != v1.end(); ++it )
{
   v2.push_back( it );
}

for ( auto it : v2 ) std::cout << *it << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```